# Square bracket in table/column name is not supported?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is square bracket in table name, column name or datatype is not supported in postgresql ?

I am getting below error while running the query in pgadmin:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test];

ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
```

SQL state: 42601

Comment: It's not supported in "Postgres", because it's not valid in SQL (the query language) and Postgres respects the SQL standard: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, why would you think it is not supported in postgreSQL? It is supported. You can try create table "[Test]" ...; Probably you mean using brackets for a name is not supported (which is common in SQL Server).

Comment: @CetinBasoz: Using `"` enables you to use _anything_ as an identifier. But _without_ the quotes `[` is illegal for identifiers. I assume Shesha comes from a SQL Server/T-SQL background - Microsoft allows to use `[..]` as an alternative for quoted identifiers.

Comment: OK I know that, but Shesa was asking "Is square bracket in table name, column name or datatype is not supported in postgresql ?". I interpreted it as if you could have brackets in name. Quesion is not clear.

Answer (score 10):

In PostgreSQL you can use double quotes :

```
CREATE TABLE "Test";
```

Same for columns, square brackets are used in SQL-Server.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the table name would be [Test] with brackets included then you would use "[Test]".

```
Create table "[Test]" ...;
```

If you meant it as an identifier, you could simply use without brackets or double quotes as Test.

```
Create table Test ...;
```

This way, you could refer to it as Test or test or tESt without double quotes in subsequent queries, ie:

```
select * from test;
```

If you use "Test" then postgreSQL would treat it as case sensitive and you would always use "Test".

```
Create table "Test" ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to emphasize the identifier name by using square brackets, then [sagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37965635/1519458) is correct. On the other hand, if you really want to use square brackets in your table name, postgresql supports this as "[Test]". In this case your table name will include square brackets. You can get additional info from [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)